# Create a Custom WordPress Page with Post titles

Tags: php, html, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a custom WordPress page that will contain only the links to all my post titles, divided on 4 column. I am also using Bootstrap with WordPress.

I created the php file, created a new page with her page atribute, but the post titles don't display.

This is the code i used:

```
    <?php
/**
 * The template used for displaying page content in questions.php
 *
 * @package fellasladies
 */
?>

<?php 

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-md-4 col-sm-4 pbox'); ?>>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php
            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'fellasladies' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
        ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'fellasladies' ), '<footer class="entry-meta"><span class="edit-link">', '</span></footer>' ); ?>
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

I really appreciate your help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I encourage you to go read about [Page Templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) on Wordpress Codex, that could help you a lot!

> Pages are one of WordPress's built-in Post Types. You'll probably want most of your website Pages to look about the same. Sometimes, though, you may need a specific Page, or a group of Pages, to display or behave differently. This is easily accomplished with Page Templates.

It seems that you have a `<?php` useless. You also don't define your template's name, which *is required*.

Comment: Can you please summarise the key findings of that article?

Comment: The page name was displayed under Page Attributes so i choosed it. However, no post title as described is shown when pointing to that page.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to start by creating a Query which fills an array with the posts you want to iterate. Read about the [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function in WordPress.

Here's an example. Note that we can't use functions which are meant to be used "in the loop" such as the_title() or the_content(). We must specify the post_id for each iteration. We should not modify the main query for situations such as this.

```
// the arguments for the get_posts() function
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post', // get posts int he "post" post_type
  'posts_per_page' => -1 // this means the array will be filled with all posts
);
$my_posts = get_posts($args);

// now we'll iterate the posts
foreach ( $my_posts as $p ) {
  // a title
  echo get_the_title($p->ID);
  // the link
  echo get_permalink($p->ID);
  // a custom field value
  echo get_post_meta($p->ID,'custom_field_key',true);
}
```

Theming what happens inside each iteration is up to you.

Good luck! :)